# How to know if a statement is true or false

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$4\mathbb{Z} \cap 3\mathbb{Z} = 12\mathbb{Z}$$

I have to establish if this statement is true or false. If it's true I have to prove it. If it's false I have to use a counterexample. How can I do it?

I think it's true because 12 can be divided by 4 and by 3 but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: This is an equality of sets.  Do you know how to prove or disprove equality for sets?

Comment: Don't be impressed by the notations, the statement only means *numbers which are both multiple of $3$ and $4$ are in fact multiples of $12$*. :o

Answer (score 5):

First of all recall the definition

$$k\mathbb{Z}=\{kn\ |\ n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

You have to show two inclusions:

"$\supseteq$" If $x\in 12\mathbb{Z}$ then by definition $x=12n$ for some $n$. But since $12=4\cdot 3$ then

$$x=12n=4\cdot 3\cdot n=4\cdot(3n)=4m$$

and again by definition $x\in 4\mathbb{Z}$. Analogously $x\in 3\mathbb{Z}$ and thus $x\in 4\mathbb{Z}\cap 3\mathbb{Z}$.

"$\subseteq$" Assume that $x\in 4\mathbb{Z}\cap 3\mathbb{Z}$. Then, by definition $x=4s$ and $x=3t$ for some $s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$. Write it down like this:

$$4s=3t$$

Now since the greatest common divisor $\gcd(3, 4)=1$ then it follows that $3$ divides $s$. In particular $s=3k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus

$$x=4s=4\cdot(3k)=12k$$

and thus $x\in 12\mathbb{Z}$. $\Box$

All of that can be generalized as follows:

> **Lemma.** Let $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then
>   $$n\mathbb{Z}\cap m\mathbb{Z}=k\mathbb{Z}$$
>   where $k=\text{lcm}(n,m)$ is the least common multiple of $n,m$.

Comment: Why is 3n equal to m?

Comment: @MarkBlack I just defined $m$ to be equal to $3n$ (to match the definition of $4\mathbb{Z}$). The symbol was not used earlier.

Comment: Do I have to write all of this to prove it or only a part of it?

Comment: @MarkBlack everything up to the white box.

Comment: What white box?

Comment: @MarkBlack "and thus $x\in 12\mathbb{Z}$. $\Box$"

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in (4\Bbb Z)\cap (3\Bbb Z)$ then there exist integers $m,n$ such that $x=4m=3n.$ Now $$x=4m=3n \implies n=x/3=4m/3=m+(m/3)   \implies (m/3)=n-m\implies $$ $ \implies m=3(n-m)\implies$ $ x=4m=4(3(n-m))=12(n-m)\in 12\Bbb Z. $

Hence $x\in (4\Bbb Z)\cap (3\Bbb Z)\implies n\in 12\Bbb  Z.$

The reverse implication is $x\in 12\Bbb Z \implies$ $ (x\in 4\Bbb Z \land x\in 3\Bbb Z)$ $\implies x\in (4\Bbb Z)\cap (3\Bbb Z)$, which should be obvious:  E.g. if $x\in 12\Bbb Z$ then there exists integer $a$ such that $x=12a,$ and then $3a\in \Bbb Z$ so $x=4(3a)\in 4 \Bbb Z.$

In general if $a,b\in \Bbb Z$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $(a\Bbb Z)\cap (b\Bbb Z) =(ab)\Bbb Z.$ Because if $\gcd (a,b)=1$ then there exist integers $x,y$ such that $$ax+by=1\quad \text {(Bezout's Identity).}$$ So if $m,n\in \Bbb Z$ then $$z=am=bn\in (a\Bbb Z)\cap (b\Bbb Z)\implies m(1-by)=m(ax)=(ma)x=zx=(nb)x\implies$$ $$\implies m=m(1-by)+mby=(nb)x+mby =b(nx+my)\implies$$ $$\implies z=am=a(b(nx+my))\in (ab)\Bbb Z.$$